# Can not reach web server from outside local network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, connection

I have a web server running on my laptop.
No problem accessing it within the network in my home by a local ip (e.g 10.0.0.3) or by the laptop name.

However, from the outside it can not be reached (by ip, I didnt purchase a domain yet).

The webserver runs on port 8888.

In the router (D-Link DSL-2760U/E1) :
1.I've configured DHCP settings to my local address by its MAC address. 
2.I've opened port 8888 and used http://www.canyouseeme.org/ to verify it is open.

Anyidea what am I missing or which tools can aid me?

Thanks,
Omer.

According to http://www.yougetsignal.com/ the port is opened.

[image]

Comment: Just a shot in the dark but did your redirect the 8888 to the right internal ip? Also, did you also use port 8888 to reach it internally, like `http://10.0.0.3:8888` (and that works) ?

Comment: yes and yes. http://10.0.0.3:8888 works fine

Comment: The full address i'm trying from outside is : http://76.176.191.45:8888/debts

which doesn't work while the following does:
http://10.0.0.3:8888/debts

Comment: Could you (from the outside) do a `telnet your_public_ip 8888` and type something and then enter. Do you get something back? Or does telnet timeout?

Comment: According to [yougetsignal](http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/) port `8888` is closed on `76.176.191.45`. Are you sure `canyouseeme` states it as open?

Comment: I just checked http://www.yougetsignal.com/ and it sais it is open

Comment: Hahaha, [this](http://i.imgur.com/4e09Elq.png) is what i get. What if you do the port test from another location (then your own network, as from outside your lan)

Comment: And [this](http://i.imgur.com/q5HjT8W.png) on [seomastering](http://www.seomastering.com/port-scanner.php). Maybe these port-scanners all trace from your current location and with "Nat loopback" on in your router all your ports seem open (because it never leaves your network). So you should do the port-scans from a different location. (Who knows a portscanner which scans from that website and where you can supply an public-ip?)

Comment: Seems the port is open, dono why it seems closed from theoutside, but I went over the router settings and talked to my ISP who verified that

Comment: but if it is indeed closed as the services you mentioned indicate what should I check? Maybe it is open but something is blocking it to the outside

Comment: Do you have access to a computer outside your network (maybe via remote control) where you can check with these services if that port is open? Was your ISP **specific** that **your** port 8888 is open (or just that they say they don't block it)? You could try openening a different port. If you click "Scan all open ports" on yougetsignal (lower right) do you get any other ports open?

Comment: when scanning all common ports all are closed. when asking to scan the specific 8888 it sais it is open. ISP confirmed that the port is open

Comment: Weird, I think you need to confirm this yourself via a computer from the outside because from my computer (and all those port-scanning sites) it is closed. Also try another port (or try several other ports).

Comment: [Another one](http://www.whatsmyip.org/port-scanner/) you can try.

Comment: what webserver are you using, and has it been configured to allow connections from any address, or just the local lan?

Comment: I'm using python bottle framework. My ip is dynamic and not a static one. could that be a problem?

Comment: No, dynamic or static would not matter. But you need to instruct `python bottle framework` to accept external access. What `run(` line do you use?

Comment: bottle.run(port=8888, host='0.0.0.0', server='paste')

Comment: That would be alright. Any firewall software on the server which would block external access (and allow internal access)? Otherwise we're back to testing on different ports and checking on an external computer.

Comment: firewall is turned off... any other ideas? maybe the issue is within bottle ?

Comment: You could try a different port in bottle (i.e. 99, a low port). You could also see what other port on the server is open (i.e. 135 and 445) and **briefly** set it open on the net and check with those port-scanners if it is open (just to see if they can be reached from the outside). What did [this one](http://www.whatsmyip.org/port-scanner/) say on port 8888?? You need to these tests with a port-scanner which scans from **that** website (and not from **your** browser. Or else you need to test from a computer from outside your lan.